# videojs-record: Rotate recorded video output

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to rotate the recorded video output of [videojs-record](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record)?

I was able to rotate the camera vertically (90deg)in the preview, but the output remains horizontal

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library like https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/ to rotate video in the browser. You can use the `rotate="-90"` option. Or do it on the server using FFmpeg with the same option.